# phpmyadmin Export table to CSV, Traditional Chinese characters turn into question marks

Tags: mysql, csv, phpmyadmin, export

I'm working on a bilingual (English & Traditional Chinese) website with the content stored in a db. I usually export the tables as CSV and input the data in bulk an then re-import it back into the table. The Chinese characters display both in the db and the website. However, whenever I export tables with Traditional Chinese characters, they turn into question marks.

I've tried changing the collation of the entire table as well as individual columns into various settings (big, binary, utf8, etc) but nothing seems to work. I've also tried using character sets in the export interface but it doesn't fix the problem either.

Is this a problem with phpmyadmin or are there some settings that could fix this? You help would be much appreciated.

Comment: same problem here.. still unsolved..

Answer (score 0):

I kinda solved this problem of exporting a table as csv that contains Chinese. But not really with phpmyadmin. You can use this export script to export the table you want that contains Chinese and it'll display properly

```
<?php
/*
 * PHP code to export MySQL data to CSV
 * http://salman-w.blogspot.com/2009/07/export-mysql-data-to-csv-using-php.html
 *
 * Sends the result of a MySQL query as a CSV file for download
 */
/*
 * establish database connection
 */
$conn = mysql_connect('MYSQL_HOST', 'MYSQL_USERNAME', 'MYSQL_PASSWORD') or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db('MYSQL_DATABASE', $conn) or die(mysql_error($conn));
mysql_query("SET character_set_results=utf8", $conn);
/*
 * execute sql query
 */
$query = sprintf('SELECT * FROM MYSQL_TABLE');
$result = mysql_query($query, $conn) or die(mysql_error($conn));
/*
 * send response headers to the browser
 * following headers instruct the browser to treat the data as a csv file called export.csv
 */
header('Content-Type: text/csv');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=export.csv');
echo "\xEF\xBB\xBF";
/*
 * output header row (if atleast one row exists)
 */
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
if ($row) {
echocsv(array_keys($row));
}
/*
 * output data rows (if atleast one row exists)
 */
while ($row) {
echocsv($row);
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
}
/*
 * echo the input array as csv data maintaining consistency with most CSV implementations
 * - uses double-quotes as enclosure when necessary
 * - uses double double-quotes to escape double-quotes 
 * - uses CRLF as a line separator
 */
function echocsv($fields)
{
$separator = '';
foreach ($fields as $field) {
    if (preg_match('/\\r|\\n|,|"/', $field)) {
        $field = '"' . str_replace('"', '""', $field) . '"';
    }
    echo $separator . $field;
    $separator = ',';
}
echo "\r\n";
}
?>
```

This code was copied and modified from the following sources:

1. http://salman-w.blogspot.hk/2009/07/export-mysql-data-to-csv-using-php.html
2. [When exported to CSV russian characters won't display](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11223156/when-exported-to-csv-russian-characters-wont-display/12097021#12097021)

Turns out the problem wasn't in the csv file but with excel. Not matter what the encoding of the csv file is, excel will always open it as ASCII, which screws up the chinese. The above code will

1. export the csv as UTF-8 encoding so Chinese can be displayed with this `mysql_query("SET character_set_results=utf8", $conn);`
2. force excel to open the csv as UTF-8 with this `echo "\xEF\xBB\xBF";`

Although this kinda solves the problem, it'd be great someone could figure out how to do this through phpmyadmin without the need for a custom export script.